# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlfiddle

I am not getting this error. Please help me out.

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 12: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not
>   null range default character

Please find a link for more [info](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3848/8).

I have created a table whose name is `Scores` and inserted `score` value in it.
My problem is that I want to calculate the total of scores who is prime number and less than 100.

Comment: your code works without exception: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69f95538138c34063b1544e2b2d47bdc

Comment: But I am getting the above error in another environment.

Comment: Where are you executing the script?

Comment: @ErgiNushi sqlfiddle

Comment: have a look at  [PL/SQL on sqlfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483450/pl-sql-on-sqlfiddle)

Comment: It works good in Oracle environment, why bother worrying why doesn't it work on sqlfiddle?

Comment: I am not sure about it. Actually I just google for plsql fiddle online and I get a link to SQL fiddle.

Comment: @hotfix 's link will do the trick.